# How do I run an electron react application correctly?

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-builder

I have an electron application and the UI is created using react.js.

For my application to work, I have to run the electron shell in a terminal window, and in another tab, I run the webpack-dev-server that emits some js code.

This is the complete setup that I need to do in order to get my application to work fine.

I want to be able to run a single command and startup the complete application. How is that achieved?

I tried the following:

I included "concurrently": "^4.1.2" in my package.json and rewrote the scripts section to look like:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm-run-all --parallel start:dev electron",
    "start:dev": "webpack-dev-server",
    "electron": "electron ."
  }
```

Now, if I run `npm start` it works but requires a reload of the app.

https://github.com/snipedown21/convertVideos-electron

With concurrently, I need to start the application with `npm run start` and then hit command + R / Ctrl + R to get the react content on the app window.

The expected behavior is to see the content on startup. How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the problem was on `start` cmd, as it executes `electron` before completion of `start:dev` due to which electron app launches before webpack-dev-server compiles the react app.

At firstly, you can execute `start:dev` cmd, wait until the completion of webpack-dev-server to compile the react app and then execute `electron` cmd.

You can use this cmd

```
 "start": "concurrently \"npm run start:dev\" \"wait-on http://localhost:4172  && npm run electron\"",
```

Here you need to add `wait-on` and `concurrently` as dev dependencies.